# Positioning a span over a div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a modal popup window and I'm trying to position my error message for a required field. As you can see, I get a scroll bar but I would like the error message to hang off of the popup window (as I've highlighted with the dashed line). Is this possible?

HTML:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Street1" data-valmsg-replace="true" style="z-index: 99999; position: absolute; top: 96.953125px; left: 315.5625px;width: 150px;"><span for="Street1" class="" style="">This is a required field.</span></span>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible? Sure. But you'll need to post more of your code, and a jsFiddle usually helps.

Comment: apply the `position:absolute` for the span and adjust its postion

Comment: what you are using is plugin for validation. that plugin is the one who controls the layout of the error msg. You need to either dive into your plugin or try to make jsfiddle example

Comment: Add the following to your span: `z-index:1000000;` Otherwise, try this: **dialog form style**: `overflow:visible;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the error message to the middle of the textbox. I didn't want to increase the width of the modal window just to make room for the error messages. That would be too much white space.